# Where can I access the files created on the windows 10 ubuntu app?

Tags: csv, ubuntu, windows-10

I downloaded the windows 10 version of ubuntu to work on a python research project for school. I created a .csv file in the ubuntu terminal but I do not know where I can access that file from.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu installed from the Microsoft Store:

> Each distribution you install through the Microsoft Store is installed to that application's appdata directory. For example: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\`<sup>[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20200531082443/https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/402)</sup>

The default Ubuntu 18.04 `/home` directory is located in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\`

Warning: Creating or modifying any files within the Windows Subsystem for Linux from Windows can result in data loss or corruption in Ubuntu, so make copies of these files before using them and use the copies in Windows, not the original files.

---

The Windows 10 April 2019 Update gives Windows Subsystem for Linux the new ability to let you access Linux files safely from Windows. WSL2 which features a true Linux kernel can be installed in Windows 10 version 2004  and later.